# What happens when a druid picks up an object which is a polymorphed creature and then tries to merge it into their Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, polymorph

One of the interesting and useful characteristics of a druid's Wild Shape is that they can merge their equipment into their beast form.

The scenario is this:

A PC from the party is turned into an object using *True Polymorph*, let's say a ring or a coin. The druid in the party picks up the object and puts it into a pouch. Then, they use their Wild Shape feature with the option of merging all equipment into themselves.

Does this work first of all? - and, if it does, what happens if the effect of *True Polymorph* ends while the druid is still in beast form?

Comment: True Polymorph does not end after an hour.  After an hour it becomes permanent.  A better way to ask the question would be what happens to such an object if True Polymorph is dispelled or cancelled by the caster by dropping concentration.

Comment: @ScottDunnington Thanks, updated the question.

Answer (score 9):

## There are no rules guidelines for this situation

Let's get the obvious out of the way. Equipment can be merged into the Wild Shaping druid, regardless if they were formerly creatures, so far so good. True Polymorph states that when it ends the target "returns to its normal form". However this is general advice, it is not normally assumed that a character polymorphed into an object has been merged into a druid which is Wild Shaping.

That's the extent of the factual information, and I doubt anyone can give you an objective answer about what is better. Whether you have the polymorphed PC merge with the druid temporarily, or have them pop out with a splat, or whatever else, all possibilities have interesting roleplay opportunities. All of which are equally valid from a rules perspective.

Comment: +1 for interesting roleplay opportunities: How to smuggle someone into any event 101

Comment: Just be consistent in your ruling.

Comment: Thanks for adding various results and as you say these could be equally valid from a rules perspective. Do you lean more towards one result than another as a DM, e.g. the polymorphed PC pops out once reverted into  their original form? That was my hunch, but I would like to have some reasoning behind it - if there is any. Or, at least a confirmation that other experienced DMs would allow this.